# How to send an output signal in a Nlsnquire terminal?

Tags: android, gpio

It's probably a stupid question, but it's my first time working in this area and the manual isn't helpful.

The terminal in question (NLS-Nquire350) has an Android OS, a barcode reader and GPIO pins (two in input and two in output according to the manual).

> "The NQuire supports interfacing with a GPIO device such as an entry/exit gate, door lock or LED lamp by connecting the signal wires to the GPIO ports."

I need to change the state of the output ports (OUT1 and OUT2) to control a gate, the manual states that I need to send these commands via escape sequences

Command to set GPO output:

```
/x1b/x7e<param1><param2>
Parameter definition:
Param1:/x30 = OUT1
/x31 = OUT2
Param2: /x30 = low
/x31 = high
E.g. setting OUT2 to low:
/x1b/x7e/x31/x30
```

The example seems quite understandable to me, there is a command and two parameters, the problem is: what should I do with it? How do I send them to the terminal? I'm sure I'm missing some basis because the manual doesn't talk about what to do with it, it seems to take it for granted.

Can anyone direct me? Thank you